# What is a good method for predicting temperature and precipitation

Tags: predictive-models, arima, prediction, differential-equations

I was wondering what is according to you the best method for predicting temperature and precipitation in say 10 days period. So far I have tried ARIMA models, which make sense, but I'm not satisfied with the prediction error and was wondering if there is better way to go about it.

Im working with data that spans over 25 years and my goal is to predict temperature and precipitation as accurately as possible, thus minimizing RMSE. I am asking general question regarding the usual practice in selecting models for such a task. The data are of course cyclical as one would expect. That is why my initial intuition went with (S)ARIMA model.

I want to forecast future values.

Comment: More context is needed to answer this question.  In particular, it needs a clear description of the data, as well as some articulation of how "best" is intended to be understood.

Comment: Do you mean *forecasting* future values, or identifying the true underlying trend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDEs are definitely one approach. I've always heard that Bayesian approaches to weather forecasting were the most accurate over a short horizon. Here's a link to a presentation by Adrian Raftery on that topic:

http://www.dtcenter.org/ensemble_presentations/3-6_RafteryDTC09.pdf

That said, there are many commercial weather prediction tools out there...here's one:

http://www.statweather.com/Index.asp?PageNo=1

Finally, simply typing "weather prediction" into LinkedIn's search engine will turn up dozens of options related to this topic.

Answer (score 1):

The univariate time series methods are not appropriate for weather prediction. Weather predictions are done using complex weather models comprising partial differential equations. For more details see the website of [Universities Center for Atmospheric Research](http://www.ucar.edu/).